# How to get the data inside a List<array>

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, winforms

example...

```
List<array> thisListOfArray = new List<array>();
List<string> thisArrayA= new List<string>();
List<string> gMaintenanceB = new List<string>();
thisArrayA.Add("ItemA1");
thisArrayA.Add("ItemA2");
thisArrayA.Add("ItemA3");
thisArrayB.Add("ItemB1");
thisArrayB.Add("ItemB2");
thisArrayB.Add("ItemB3");
thisListOfArray.Add(thisArrayA.ToArray());
thisListOfArray.Add(thisArrayB.ToArray());
```

I want to get every value that I have inputted inside the `thisListOfArray`.

Comment: It is `List<string[]>`

Comment: In `C#` arrays are denoted by `type[]`. Thus `List<array>` needs to become `List<string[]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it following way. here is the code

```
List<string[]> thisListOfArray = new List<string[]>();
List<string> thisArrayA = new List<string>();
List<string> thisArrayB = new List<string>();
thisArrayA.Add("ItemA1");
thisArrayA.Add("ItemA2");
thisArrayA.Add("ItemA3");
thisArrayB.Add("ItemB1");
thisArrayB.Add("ItemB2");
thisArrayB.Add("ItemB3");
thisListOfArray.Add(thisArrayA.ToArray());
thisListOfArray.Add(thisArrayB.ToArray());

List<string> lstNewstring = new List<string>();

foreach (var strArray in thisListOfArray)
{
    foreach (var str in strArray)
    {
        lstNewstring.Add(str);
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(lstNewstring.Count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
List<List<string>> thisListOfArray = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> thisArrayA = new List<string>();
List<string> gMaintenanceB = new List<string>();
thisArrayA.Add("ItemA1");
thisArrayA.Add("ItemA2");
thisArrayA.Add("ItemA3");
gMaintenanceB.Add("ItemB1");
gMaintenanceB.Add("ItemB2");
gMaintenanceB.Add("ItemB3");
thisListOfArray.Add(thisArrayA);
thisListOfArray.Add(gMaintenanceB);

foreach (var itm in thisListOfArray.SelectMany(item => item))
{
    MessageBox.Show(itm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

- `List<string[]> listOfArray`
- `string[] array`

Add the array to the List with `listOfArray.Add(array);`
Not sure where you'll be getting `array` from.